# django how to upload folder

Tags: python, django, file-upload, upload, uploading

I know how to upload multiple files through django, but I have a problem when uploading a folder if there are subfolders in it. The django can't receive subfolders. I found the reason, because browser use '.' to represent a folder, but django can't parse it then stop parsing. Is there an elegant way to fix it?

python code:

```
def uploader_single(request):
    data = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if True:
            for afile in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
                new_file = UploadFileSingle(file = afile)
                new_file.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
        else:
            print "form is not valid"
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        print 'not post'
```

Python code:

```
class UploadFileSingle(models.Model):
    file        = models.FileField(upload_to='files/%Y/%m/%d', models.FilePath)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    models.FilePathField.recursive = True
    models.FilePathField.allow_folders = True
    updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def some_folder = FilePathField(path='some_path', recursive=True, allow_files=True, allow_folders=True,)'
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="file" name="file" multiple = "true" webkitdirectory="true" directory = "true"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is newer topic which asks the same question and I have tried to answer:

[Django directory upload get sub-directory names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654704/django-directory-upload-get-sub-directory-names/40812464#40812464)

Basically it is the default behavior of Django if you want to have different behavior you need to write your own upload handlers

Answer (score 0):

I came up with easy solution for this problem.

- You could get folder name via html and javascript in frontend
- pass it as a value to hidden form field
- in backend you can create a directory with that name
- and upload files in this directory.

*HTML*

```
<input type="hidden" name="dir_name" id="id_dir_name">
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="selectFolder(event)" webkitdirectory="" multiple="" required="" directory="" id="id_file">
```

*JS*

```
function selectFolder(e) {
    var theFiles = e.target.files;
    var relativePath = theFiles[0].webkitRelativePath;
    var folder = relativePath.split("/");
    $("#" + id).val(folder[0]);
}
```

*views*

```
directory_name = form.cleaned_data['dir_name']
os.mkdir(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, directory_name))
handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'], directory_name)
```

Comment: It's much more recomended to write your own upload handlers

Answer (score -5):

you can use django filer

rerfer:https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer

Comment: Thank you very much. But could you please explain how could I exactly apply filter on my case? Thank you.

Comment: django filter can not do that. My conclusion is django can't do it yet.

Comment: Nothing to do with the question